# WPF Command binding in button inside a materialDesign dialog

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, material-design-in-xaml

Im new to WPF and material desing. And im trying to make a dialog for a confirmation of a button, but when i bind the command and press the button it never gets to the method.

The dialog is made in a dynamicly populated listBox.

**Window**

```
   <ListBox  Height="585" 
         Name="NoteList"
         ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"   
         ItemsSource="{Binding dtoRecetas}" Grid.Row="1">

        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

               <!--VERSION CARTAS-->
               <materialDesign:Card Style="{StaticResource cardsRecetas}" >
                  <Grid>
                      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                           <RowDefinition Height="150"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="170"/>
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                          <!-- DIALOGO DE ELIMINAR RECETA-->
                          <materialDesign:DialogHost  CloseOnClickAway="True" >
                             <materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>
                                 <StackPanel Margin="16">
                                    <TextBlock>Deseas eliminar esta receta</TextBlock>

                                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"  HorizontalAlignment="Right">

                                       <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                                        IsDefault="True"
                                                        Margin="0 8 8 0"
                                                        Command="{Binding Path=comandoDeleteReceta}"
                                                        CommandParameter="{Binding idReceta}">
                                                    Aceptar
                                       </Button>

                                      <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFlatButton}"
                                                        Margin="0 8 8 0"
                                                        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.CloseDialogCommand}">
                                              Cancelar
                                       </Button>
                                     </StackPanel>

                                    </StackPanel>
                              </materialDesign:DialogHost.DialogContent>

                             <Button x:Name="btnDeleteReceta" Style="{StaticResource btnDeleteReceta}" 
                                        Tag="{Binding idReceta}"
                                        Command="{x:Static materialDesign:DialogHost.OpenDialogCommand}">

                                   <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="RemoveCircle" />

                                </Button>
                          </materialDesign:DialogHost>

                       </StackPanel>


                    </Grid>
                </materialDesign:Card>

            </DataTemplate>

            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"  ></WrapPanel>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        </ListBox>
```

**ViewModel**

```
 public class VerRecetasViewModel : BaseViewModel 
    {
        public Command comandoDeleteReceta { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<DTOReceta> dtoRecetas { get; set; }

        public VerRecetasViewModel()
        {
            RecetasController recController = new RecetasController();
            dtoRecetas = new ObservableCollection<DTOReceta>(recController.getAllRecetas());

            comandoDeleteReceta = new Command();
            comandoDeleteReceta.CanExecuteFunc = obj => true;
            comandoDeleteReceta.ExecuteFunc = deleteReceta;
        }



        public void deleteReceta(object parameter)
        {
            int idReceta = (int)parameter;
            RecetasController recController = new RecetasController();
            recController.deleteReceta(idReceta);
        }


    }
```

The desired behavior is that when they press "Aceptar" it gets to the "deleteReceta" method, but as right now it looks like is not finding the binded command.
[image]

The command class is working and i use commands in other windows this way and it works, i think im losing the context from the dialog or creating it wrong. I tried this way and adding relative source to the binding, but i dont know what the ancestortype should be.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's a problem with the DataContext. So I would set the dataContext of the view like this :
`d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance {x:Type vm:VerRecetasViewModel}}"`

and in the ListBox, bind the command on the button like this :

```
Command="{Binding DataContext.comandoDeleteReceta, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Its not problem of the implementation of the command, i already have that in a class Command i made, slightlty different, but it works in the other windows and viewmodels.
I tried with your version, but it also didnt work. The problem is that the button is not finding the commands or the viewmodel, and i dont know how to change its data context to the view model or use the relative source properly.

Comment: I've edited my answer, have a look again and let me know if it helps :)

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot man, I am liking WPF but im struggling a lot with bindings. Now to access the idReceta as a command parameter that i have in that card of the collection (     CommandParameter="{Binding idReceta}" as of right now). Should i also use this relative source?
Thanks again for all the help!

Comment: Yeah, you could try that. I also think it would be better in the future if you tried writing a ViewModel class for the recipes, so something like `RecetaViewModel` and in your `VerRectasViewModel` have a `List<RecetaViewModel>` . This way you could treat each one of them separately, and code to perform actions on them would be handled in `RecetaViewModel`. And if you wanted to add/remove, you would handle that in the `VerRecetasViewModel`. Hope it makes sense